# Can't set up awesome-terminal-fonts

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, zsh

I'm trying to setup a great `Powerlevel9K` prompt with `awesome-terminal-fonts` and don't succeed. I have `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` installed, `powerline` installed for terminal and `vim` and `nerd-font` installed too.

I followed line by line the install process here: https://github.com/gabrielelana/awesome-terminal-fonts/blob/master/README.md#how-to-install-linux

I have multiple `10-symbols.conf` files in multiple folders and i don't know which one is effective, i also don't understand what font to replace after `PragmataPro` in `10-symbols.conf` file ... is it one of the 4 fonts in the .build folder or one random font we like ?

If someone uses Powerlevel9K with `awesome-terminal-fonts`, every help is welcoming.

Comment: THX @wjandrea for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one in your HOME directory should be most authoritative (should be in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-symbols.conf`).

`PragmataPro` should be replaced with one font you like that is available/installed on your machine (use `fc-list` to see the complete list).

The `10-symbols.conf` should have some documentation in it, if something is not clear then please open an issue [here](https://github.com/gabrielelana/awesome-terminal-fonts/issues) so that we can improve it.